# Err cleartext not permitted NativeScript?

Tags: android, angularjs, mobile-development, mobile-web, nativescript

Получаю ошибку при попытке прочитать в веббраузере ссылку

```
192.168.1.161:8081/api/get_news  

http://192.168.1.161:8081/api/get_news
```

Выдаёт ошибку.
Как исправить, если приложение на Angular Nativescript?

Изменил: Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.161</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://192.168.1.161</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="10000"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

По идее у вас должен быть `AndroidManifest.xml`. Туда надо добавить в тэг `application` атрибут `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: @"ЮрийСПб♦" добавил, но всёравно ошибка. На других сайтах тоже пишут добавить в манифест, но не работает. Что может быть ещё?

Comment: @RakzinRoman, странно, должно работать) Покажите каких-нибудь деталей... Например под какую версию SDK сборка идёт, есть ли в манифесте разрешение на интернет, какая версия вашей технологии - причин может быть много. Может даже у вас приложение не пересобралось и проблема решена, просто вам надо корректно пересобрать артифакт.

Comment: @"ЮрийСПб♦" манифест выложил. Ну я выключил и запустил заново Nativescript. По-идее он пересобрался заново, хотя- всё ли он пересобирал- я не знаю

Comment: @RakzinRoman, вы привели файл с настройкой для доменов, но в манифест не добавили `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` как написано здесь: https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6

Comment: Также уточните где и как вы приложение пишете-собираете. В AndroidStudio, например, по умолчанию включена опция неполной пересборки и она может глючить. В какой IDE вы пишете? Нужно больше деталей, например на какой версии ОС тестируете, какая максимальная стоит (если понизить максимальную может заработать временно, на год или около того)